# procedure return true or false if a procedure is successful PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE p1
AS

PROCEDURE exem1 (p_value OUT BOOLEAN);

PROCEDURE exem2 (p_value OUT BOOLEAN);

END p1;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE body p1
AS
   PROCEDURE exam1 (p_value IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'NULL')
   IS
if exam2(p_value);
then
    p_value:= true;
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('successful!!!!');
else
p_value:=false
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Error!!!!');
   BEGIN
      end if;
   END exam1;
end p1;/
```

but it's not working

Comment: Please elaborate on "not working".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified your code to make something that compiles and runs without error:

```
OPS$ORACLE@UPGR>set serveroutput on
OPS$ORACLE@UPGR>--
OPS$ORACLE@UPGR>CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE p1 AS
  2  FUNCTION  exam1 (p_value IN VARCHAR2) RETURN BOOLEAN;
  3  PROCEDURE exam2 (p_value IN OUT VARCHAR2);
  4  END p1;
  5  /

Package created.

OPS$ORACLE@UPGR>show errors
No errors.
OPS$ORACLE@UPGR>CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE body p1 AS
  2  
  3  FUNCTION exam1 (p_value IN VARCHAR2) RETURN BOOLEAN
  4  IS
  5  BEGIN
  6   RETURN (p_value = 'OK');
  7  END;
  8  
  9  PROCEDURE exam2 (p_value IN OUT VARCHAR2)
 10  IS
 11   BEGIN
 12   IF exam1(p_value)
 13   THEN
 14    BEGIN
 15     p_value:= 'true';
 16     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('successful!!!!');
 17    END;
 18   ELSE
 19    BEGIN
 20    p_value:='false';
 21    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Error!!!!');
 22    END;
 23   END IF;
 24   END;
 25  END;
 26  /

Package body created.

OPS$ORACLE@UPGR>show errors
No errors.
OPS$ORACLE@UPGR>declare
  2   v varchar2(5);
  3  begin
  4  v := 'OK';
  5  p1.exam2(v);
  6  dbms_output.put_line('v=' || v);
  7  end;
  8  /
successful!!!!
v=true

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not working because you have an `OUT` parameter in the specification and an `IN` parameter in the declaration.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE p1
AS

PROCEDURE exem1 (p_value OUT BOOLEAN);                        -- OUT

PROCEDURE exem2 (p_value OUT BOOLEAN);                        -- OUT

END p1;
/
```

compared to:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE body p1
AS
   PROCEDURE exam1 (p_value IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'NULL')       -- IN
   IS
   BEGIN
     NULL; 
     -- your code here
   END exam1;

   PROCEDURE exam2 (p_value IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'NULL')       -- IN
   IS
   BEGIN
     NULL; 
     -- your code here
   END exam1;
end p1;
/
```

You need to have the same signature for the procedures in both the header and body.

Once you've done that then you can fix the other syntax errors within the individual procedures but the first thing you should do is work out what inputs and outputs your procedures have and make the signatures consistent.